# Profinite completion of local Mordell-Weil group

Tags: number-theory, elliptic-curves, arithmetic-geometry

Let $K$ be a finite extension of $\Bbb{Q}_p$.
Let $E/K$ be an elliptic curve over $K$.

Let $E(K)$ be the Mordell-Weil group of $E/K$.

Let $\widehat{E(K)}$ be the profinite completion of $E(K)$, that is, its completion with respect to finite index subgroups.

Is it true that $E(K)=\widehat{E(K)}$ ?

If we admit the result $E(K)\cong {\Bbb{Z}_p}^{[K:\Bbb{Q}_p]}\times (\text{finite group})$, it is true.

But I'm seeking a more elementary way without heavy machinery.
Thank you for your help.

cf.
$E(K)\cong {\Bbb{Z}_p}^{[K:\Bbb{Q}_p]}\times (\text{finite group})$ is in Theorem 5.2(a) of [Mat] A. Mattuck, Abelian varieties over p-adic ground fields, Ann. of Math. (2) 62 (1955), 92– 119.

Comment: Please proofread your questions before posting them.

Comment: @Aphelli Sorry and thank you very much for your correction.

Comment: I believe that your question is underspecified. Do you refer to the group-theoretic profinite completion (with respect to *any* subgroup of finite index, however ugly topologically speaking), or the “topological” profinite completion (with respect to open subgroups of finite index)? What counts as “heavy machinery” for you?

Comment: @Aphelli. I meant purely group-theoretic profinite completion. ''Heavy machinery'' is $E(K)\cong {\Bbb{Z}_p}^{[K:\Bbb{Q}_p]}\times (\text{finite group})$(firstly proved by Mattuck) in this context, and I want to understand $\widehat{E(K)}=E(K)$ without using this isomorphism if possible.

Comment: I was surprised to find that the answer changes depending on whether we consider completion to be topological or not

Comment: The answer doesn’t change (they *are* isomorphic, after all). But one sort of introduces a new step in the argument (you have to show that all finite-index subgroups are open).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily check that $E(K)$ is a topological group that continuously embeds as a closed subspace $\mathbb{P}^2(K)$, hence it is a compact and totally disconnected topological group. That it is profinite (and thus isomorphic to its profinite completion) follows from the relevant Bourbaki volume (referred to in the beginning of Serre’s *Galois Cohomology*).

You can also avoid having to refer to Bourbaki by the following method:

**Lemma:** Every subgroup $nE(K)$ for $n \geq 1$ is open.

*Proof*: since it’s a compact subgroup, it’s enough to show that it has finite index, ie that $E(K)/nE(K)$ is finite.

Now, $E(K)/nE(K) \rightarrow H^1(K,E[n])$ is injective, so it’s enough to show that $H^1(K,E[n])$ is finite.

There is a finite Galois extension $L/K$ such that $E[n] \cong \mu_n \oplus \mu_n$ as $G_L$-modules, hence $H^1(L,E[n])=H^1(L,\mu_n)^{\oplus 2}=(L^{\times}/L^{\times n})^{\oplus 2}$ which is finite.

The kernel of the restriction map $H^1(K,E[n]) \rightarrow H^1(L,E[n])$ is exactly $H^1(\mathrm{Gal}(L/K), E[n](L))$: it’s the cohomology of a finite group in a finite module, hence is finite.

Finally $H^1(K,E[n])$ is finite, QED.

**Corollary:** every finite index subgroup of $E(K)$ is open.

*Proof*: a subgroup of index $n$ contains $nE(K)$.

Thus the map $E(K) \rightarrow \widehat{E(K)}$ is continuous between compact spaces with dense image, hence it is onto. To show it is an isomorphism (hence an homeomorphism since both spaces are Hausdorff compact), all we need to do is prove that it is injective, or, to put it differently, that the intersection of all subgroups of finite index of $E(K)$ is trivial.

A family of subgroups of $E(K)$ with finite index with trivial intersection is given, if I’m not mistaken, by the theory of the formal group (see the homonymous chapter of Silverman).

Comment: It was great for studying because, although compactness is good, I was wondering why openness follows from finite index properties. Thank you very much !

Comment: By the way, for the proof of the lemma, by the theory of formal group, $E(K)$ contains a finite index subgroup $H$ and there is a surjection from $E(K)/H$ to $E(K)/nE(K)$. Isn't it enough ?

Comment: (First comment): that’s because the group is the complement of the finite union of its finitely many (closed) non-trivial translates.(Second comment): It is indeed enough if you can show that $H$ is in fact open. It’s very possible that you can also derive the result in a much easier way using the theory of the formal group.