# Topology in the context of Pontryagin dual

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, definition, topological-groups, duality-theorems

Let $A$ be an abelian group.

The definition of the Pontryagin dual of $A$ is $\text{Hom}_{\text{conti}}(A, \mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z})$.

In this context, what are the topologies on $A$ and $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$?

Is it the cofinite topology on $A$ and the discrete topology on $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$, or does that depend on the situation?

in the case where $A=\widehat{E(\mathbb{Q})}$($\widehat{E(\Bbb{Q})}$ is profinite completion of $E(\Bbb{Q})$  cf. [Profinite completion of local Mordell-Weil group](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4863522/profinite-completion-of-local-mordell-weil-group)) and $E$ is an elliptic curve defined over $\mathbb{Q}$, $A$ is an infinite group. However, we usually consider its Pontryagin dual. I'm especially interested in this example.

Supplementary information in response to comments：

In the case where $A=\widehat{E(\mathbb{Q})}$ and $E$ is an elliptic curve defined over $\mathbb{Q}$, $A$ is an infinite group. However, we usually consider its Pontryagin dual. I'm especially interested in this example.

Comment: This is a restricted view of Pontryagin duality.  It applies, for example, if $A$ is a **finite** Abelian group.  For the original version, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pontryagin_duality

Comment: @GEdgar  In the case where $A=E(\mathbb{Q})$ and $E$ is an elliptic curve defined over $\mathbb{Q}$, $A$ is an infinite group. However, we usually consider its Pontryagin dual. I'm especially interested in this example.

Comment: Where did you see anyone discuss the Pontryagin dual of $E(\mathbb{Q})$?

Comment: @Aphelli It was a typo, thank you.

Comment: My question still applies, though. How is the profinite completion of $E(\mathbb{Q})$ (or its Pontryagin dual) interesting when it’s just the sum of a finite free $\hat{Z}$-module (whose rank is a major headache to understand) and of a finite group?

Comment: Pontryagin used continuous homomorphisms into $\mathbb R/\mathbb Z$, that is, a circle.  That has a standard topology.  In case of a group where all elements have finite order, the homomorphisms have values in the subgroup $\mathbb Q/\mathbb Z$.

Comment: @Aphelli. Let $K$ be a number field and $E/K$ be an elliptic curve.
If we assume finiteness of $Sha(E/K)$, there is exact sequence
$$0\to Sha(E/K)\to H^1(G_K,E) \to \bigoplus_{v} {H^1(G_{K_v},E)}\to {\widehat{E(K)}}^*\to0$$
where ${\widehat{E(K)}}^*$ is Pontryagin dual of $\widehat{E(K)}$. This exact sequence and argument about Pontryagin dual of $\widehat{E(K)}$ appears in Milne's 'Arithmetic duality theorems'. but I don't know what topology on $\widehat{E(K)}$, so I asked this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, a clarification following the comments about Pontryagin duality. It indeed concerns a duality theory on locally compact abelian groups, and the dual of such a group $A$ is $\mathrm{Hom}_{C^0}(A,\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z})$ endowed with the compact open topology.

In particular, this duality preserves finite groups and exchanges compact groups and discrete groups.

Note that any continuous homomorphism from a pro-finite group $A$ into $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$ must have open kernel (that is because $A$ has arbitrarily small open subgroups, while there is a neighborhood of $0$ in $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$ containing no non-trivial subgroup). In particular, its image is finite, and the homomorphism factors through $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$ *endowed with its discrete topology*.

This is why we can say that the Pontryagin dual of a profinite group $A$ is exactly $\mathrm{Hom}_{C^0}(A,\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z})$, where $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$ is discrete.

And indeed, it seems that the topology on $\widehat{E(\mathbb{Q})}$ should be the pro-finite topology, since there’s no other reasonable candidate.

Notes:

1. in particular, no weaker topology on $\widehat{E(\mathbb{Q})}$ is Hausdorff (let alone locally compact),
2. in the exact sequence, the only reasonable topology to put on the direct sum is discrete (see *Arithmetic Duality Theorems*, Corollary I.3.4), so the topology on $\widehat{E(\mathbb{Q})}^{\ast}$ is expected to be discrete, hence $\widehat{E(\mathbb{Q})}$ has to be compact.